# How to run a promise

Tags: node.js, promise, chaining

I know that't very silly, but how to start a promise chain? I have, for example,

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    return resolve("Hi from promise after timeout");
  },1000);
});
```

How to run it? It should be like that,

```
when(p)
.then(function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

But `when` is not defined.

Comment: Promises are not "run" or "started". They are simple values that represent the outcome of an already-running asynchronous operation (`setTimeout` in your case) which is started when the promise is created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
p.then(function(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks.